# Does unlocking an account that isn't currently locked from within ADUC reset the number of previously-entered incorrect passwords?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

Assume the following within an environment that has an account lockout threshold set to 3 - meaning that if 3 incorrect passwords are entered, a user account becomes locked:

1. User A types 2 incorrect passwords at the Windows logon screen - entering another incorrect password would cause their account to be locked at this point
2. From within the ADUC MMC snap-in, a domain administrator navigates to the Properties dialog for User A's account, and from the "Account" tab checks the "Unlock Account" checkbox and hits the "OK" button

Considering that entering a final incorrect password for User A would have caused the account to lock before the actions carried out as part of step 2, can User A now enter an incorrect password without their account locking - does ticking the "Unlock Account" checkbox when an account isn't locked reset the count of incorrect passwords that have been entered?

Comment: You could test this in like 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not. You would want to increase the number of failed attempts before an account lockout occurs or reset the user's password to something they can remember. I cannot think of any use case where unlocking an account that is already unlocked to reset a failed password attempt counter would be required.